# How can I optimize my algorithm by replacing if-then-else statements with case statements?

Tags: data-structures, nested-loops, pseudocode

One may consider using **case** rather than **if-then-else** statements. If there are different cases, then the code goes to the right choice. This will save time without going through everything.

```
If f_op is v_op then
    If o_op == f_op then
        If (o_r_type == "C" AND f_r_type == "D") OR 
           (o_r_type == "D" AND f_r_type == "C") OR 
           (o_r_type == "C" AND f_r_type == "C") then
             do nothing 
        else if o_r_type == "D" AND f_r_type == "D" then
            v_b.add(i)

     else if o_op_cat == f_op_cat then
            v_b.add(i)
```

How to modify above ***pseudocode*** and use case statements instead of if-then-else.

Comment: First measure and benchmark to make sure this *needs* "optimization". If it's not one of the top-three bottlenecks, it's probably no use.

Comment: And with that said, the conditions are too complex to be made into a `switch`. You can't really have logical AND or OR operations in a `switch`. The `switch` statement can select only based on (numeric) *value*, not complex conditions or strings.

Comment: What language is that???? `If`, `is`, `lack of parenthesis`, `comparison of strings with ==`, ... :-)

Comment: I edited the question ... it is a pseudocode

Comment: My comments were written when the original C language tag was there. In C what you want is not possible. In other languages it could be possible. So please, don't show pseudo-code, show us a proper [mre] in the actual language you're programming in. And please note that optimization question in pseudo-code doesn't have any meaning. Optimization is very language dependent.

Comment: If this is pseudo-code, then you can make up whatever syntax you need. `switch (o_r_type, f_r_type) case ("C", "D"), ("D", "C"), ("C", "C"):` Is that legal pseudo-code? Sure! Everything is legal in pseudo-code!

Comment: Thank you, but it is actually a pseudocode that I need to add it to my paper. The programming language is not matter. I just want to modify the above pseudocode to use case statements instead of if-then-else.

Comment: But ***why***? What is the problem with the "code" you show? Why does it have to be in a "switch"-like statement instead? What is the original and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? And as mentioned by @RaymondChen, you can just make up your own pseudo-code syntax, it doesn't have to bear any resemblance to an existing language.

Comment: What are the possible values for `f_r_type` and `o_r_type`?

Comment: @trincot, two possible values, D "Data" and C "Control".

Comment: In that case your last `else` block will never enter, as you have already managed all (four) possibilities in the two previous blocks. So you will first have to take a step back and verify the correctness of this code, before considering refactoring it.

Comment: OK, I see you have changed your code to make that final `else` relate to a different `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the possible values of `f_r_type` and `o_r_type` are "C" and "D" (confirmed in comments) there are some remarks to make:

- when `if o_r_type == "D" AND f_r_type == "D" then` is executed, that condition will always be found to be true: all other possibilities were already excluded by the previous `if` condition.
- Related: the longer `if` condition (with three combination tests) tests the opposite of the next `if` condition, and so you could reduce code by only using that next condition.
- The very first two `if` statements can be joined into one `if` statement.
- As there is only one action that is or is not performed (`v_b.add(i)`), you should only need one `if` statement that combines all the conditions for it into one.

Your code would do the same if it were written like this:

```
if (f_op == v_op AND ((o_r_type == "D" AND f_r_type == "D") 
                       OR (o_op_cat == f_op_cat)) then
    v_b.add(i)
```

Here there is no gain for using a `switch` statement, as you really only have one case.